How to automate build of library before main project compilation?
I am working on a git repo containing a main Visual Studio solution. In the repository there is a submodule included (concretely the SDL3 library), which also includes a .sln file for generating the DLL/LIB files.
Starting from scratch, the steps I have to follow are:

Clone the main repo.
Go to submodule SDL path, open .sln and compile.
Close Visual Studio and copy the .dll to my project path.
Open my .sln and compile it.

Which strategy would you recommend me to automate this process so it's all made under the main compilation?

Add the vcxproj files from the SDL3 library to your solution and setup build dependencies. Or move to a CMake/Conan based build system (if you're planning on using a seperate build server).

Since you want to improve the build process, I recommend switching to a cross-platform build system first.

Is there any update? Are you using VS2022? You can create project dependencies.

Try to follow this workflow:

Clone the main repo with the SDL submodule
Open the main solution (.sln) and ensure the SDL project is part of it.
Build the main solution, which automatically builds the SDL project as a dependency.
Post-build step copies the SDL3 library to the main project’s output folder automatically.

This workflow probably needs to modify your main solution to depend on SDL by adding the SDL project (SDL3.sln or its .vcxproj file) into your main solution. Also modify the MSBuild process to ensure that SDL3 library gets built and the library is copied at the right stage.
